# Design is not right in High resolution devices

Tags: android

my design is fine in android 2.1 and fine in android 4.0 normal resolution devices but when I run my application on tablet its design is totally changed, help me

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/bowlbackground" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/hkk"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="54dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="05dp" >

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/hll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="54dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="143dp" >

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/hll2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="54dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp" >

      </LinearLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation

res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density
res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density
res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra high density
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Designing for phone and tablets are different.
2. Avoid using fixed width and height sizes for views(unless its really
   unavoidable).[See this](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html) for more info
3. Refer the doc for [supporting multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html). It helps for designing for tablets.

Comment: Just adding to that, make sure you use [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) so that you can better use the extra real estate you get from the larger screens.

Comment: hi @RKN i have use Your given link, now i am using layout-xlarge and layout-xlarge-land, now i simply set the margin top left everything but also again setting is not as like i define